# Is it possible to assign port mapping to an existing Docker container by iptables on Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, networking, redis, iptables

Operating system : ubuntu 16.04 LTS ,here's my problem.

Recently I'm building a application rely on a Redis(Docker) offered data service. A customary way of creating new Redis service is kind of like this:

```sh
docker pull redis:latest
docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis:latest
```

Assuming my WAN IP is 201.201.201.201 ,then it should just fine to access Redis via address:201.201.201.201:6379.

However this approach exposes a redis server's port to public network ,even though you can give a supper long password ,potential safety hazard remains.

Since docker do not support port mapping changing within a running container ,I need to shut down the whole docker service ,that takes a long time ,nearly impossible.

Then I'm trying to use IP table mapping instead of creating a docker map ,due to iptables 's flexibility ,theoretically it allows  benefits from both sides -- uoload files from wherever else in the world(out side zz) ,but can also close this

```sh
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 172.245.210.199 -p tcp --dport 6379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.5:6379
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 172.17.0.5 -p tcp --dport 6379 -j SNAT --to 172.17.0.1
```

But it do not work ,I can't ping container 17.17.0.162
Does anyone knows resolution ,or could propose some other ways to implement this port mapping (such as nginx or caddy?)

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379 redis` to make it accessible only from the same physical host, or leave off the `-p` option altogether to have it accessible only from other Docker containers (you probably need to `docker create network` and run all of your containers on that same `--net`).  This does require deleting and recreating your containers.  If very long startup time is a problem, I'd suggest addressing this as a problem on its own.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is to use an assistant container, in this container add port forward for your service container which did not do port mapping:

```
docker run -idt --link redis -p 6379:6379 alpine/socat TCP4-LISTEN:6379,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:redis:6379
```

Above container will use `--link redis` so it can resolve the name of your `redis container`, and when receive the traffic from host's 6379, it will first forward to assistant container's 6379, then will use `socat` to forward the traffic to the `redis container`'s 6379, so it works although your service container did not port mapping 6379.

As `--link` was deprecated, you can also customize your network, as you like:

```
docker network create my_network
docker network connect my_network redis
docker run -idt --network my_network -p 6379:6379 alpine/socat TCP4-LISTEN:6379,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:redis:6379
```

Comment: please note that `--link` is deprecated and its better to use `networks` instead